# Angular, i18n, adding translations - workflow

Tags: angular-i18n

I read this from the Angular documentation: 
https://angular.io/guide/i18n

and something isn't clear to me: Once translations are added to an app and the source files are created with "ng xi18n" it will happen that the app code is modified after words and new translations added. How these new translations are identified and how should they be integrated into the existing language translations? I mean the first translation files went to the translator, came back, were integrated but now the newly added elements to be translated are not in there. How is the process of integrating these new elements to translate?

Thanks a lot for any feedback !
Regards, 
Fabianus